# How to declare and assign an array without the app crashing?

Tags: java, android, arrays, object, loops

Basically, I'm implemeting a reversi app for android for my year 13 coursework and this snippet of code is meant to setup the board which is shown here as an array of the class position. However, when run, the app crashes.

```
Position[][] board = new Position[7][7]; //declaring the board//

for(int n = 0; n < 8; n ++){

        ...


    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ){
        final ImageView button = new ImageView(this);

        final int countN = n;
        final int countI = i;

        board[countI][countN].isPositionEmpty = true; //assigning a value//
```

Any help would be much appreciated!! thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop goes from 0 to 7 which is actually 8 cells. So you need 8 position objects.

```
Position[][] board = new Position[8][8]
```

or if you want it to be a 7 by 7 board you need to stop at the 6th index

```
for (int i =0; i <7 ; i++)
```

Answer (score 5):

You've only allocated a 7x7 array, but you're trying to use it as an 8x8 array.

Change to use:

```
Position[][] board = new Position[8][8];
```

Or preferably, have a constant which is used in multiple places:

```
private static final int BOARD_SIZE = 8;

...
Position[][] board = new Position[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZESIZE];

for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

An array allocation like this:

```
Foo[] array = new Foo[size];
```

creates an array with `size` elements; valid indexes are in the range 0 to `size - 1` inclusive.

Comment: Ahh! thought it included zero! i'll test it now!

Answer (score 4):

You have to insantiate every index of your matrix too.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ){
        board[countI][countN] = new Position();
        board[countI][countN].isPositionEmpty = true; //assigning a value//
}
```

Comment: Already done this elsewhere in the program, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

```
// Bad:
Position[][] board = new Position[7][7];
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ){
  ...

// Better:
Position[][] board = new Position[8][8];
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ){
  ...

// Best:
Position[][] board = new Position[8][8];
for(int i = 0; i < board[0].length; i++ ){
  ...
```

PS:

You not only need to initialize the array (allocate space for each row and each column of your "container"); you*also* need to initialize each *element* of the array (e.g. "array[i][j] = new Position()").